# Error when making a PointerProperty of the type bpy.types.GPencilLayer

Tags: grease-pencil, properties

I'm defining a class like:

```
class MyCustomClass(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    gplayer_A:bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.GPencilLayer, name="Layer A")

    ...
```

`gplayer_A` is supposed to store a grease pencil layer I then select in the UI with the `prop_search`

I register the class as normal (the addon and other properties worked as expected).

But when I added that `PointerProperty` I got the error:

```
ValueError: bpy_struct "MyCustomClass" registration error: 'gplayer_A' PointerProperty could not register (see previous error)
```

Previous error (ignoring the line that is about when the register happens), says:

```
TypeError: PointerProperty(...) expected an RNA type derived from ID or ID Property Group
```

I get that [GPencilLayer is a bpy_struct (from the API)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct).
But, I need that property to store a Grease Pencil Layer. I can make the type of the PointerProperty as `bpy.types.PropertyGroup`. But then the layer is not stored (and when I select one with `prop_search` in the UI, it disappears).

Any clue?

Comment: Hello. You won't be able to store this in a PropertyGroup. You'll have to store a `StringProperty` with the name of the layer. And have some functionality to make sure the property is updated when the name changes, or make sure the name never changes

Comment: @Gorgious thank you so much for the help, much appreciated. Seems you are right, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Just in case, do you have an idea about how to detect the layer name has changed? I learned about bpy.app.handlers, and I was wondering if it was able to kinda add a callback to an operator or something (like, if renaming a layer happens, trigger a function or something like that) (?)

Comment: You can look into msgbus, this lets you subscribe to special events. I don't know about grease pencil layers though. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html There are some topics about it here on BSE too

Comment: wow. This is super useful and very handy! Again, much appreciated friend, hope you have a nice week @Gorgious, thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: My pleasure. :) cheers